# Download and use FontFamily in Xamarin Android app

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, font-family

I am trying to download and use the Montserrat font family but I can't understand how to use the ttf file in my xamarin android project. I am downloading the ttf from this site https://fonts.google.com/ . Can anyone help me? Thanks a lot.

Comment: please post code you have tried, for community to help you better.

Comment: I was following this documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/resources-in-android/fonts but I was not able to solve it. But now I solve it. You just have to set to the textview this  tv.Typeface = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Assets, "fonts/PermanentMarker.ttf"), and putt the tff file inside Assets/fonts folder.

Answer (score 2):

You can work with fonts in android using [Typeface](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Typeface.html).
To use your custom downloaded fonts put them in your assets folder (better to make a subfolder named Fonts) then make a typeface using:

```
Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Application.Context.Assets, "Fonts/yourfontname.ttf");
```